# Riotjs nested tags options are undefined

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I am using riotjs library and have two tags "comment-list" and "comment".

comment-list :

```
<comment-list>
    <div each={com in comments} >
        <comment level={opts.level} comment={com} type={opts.level == 0 ? "parent" : "child"} ctype={commentType}></comment>
    </div>

    <div show={opts.level == 0}>
        <a id="load-trigger" onclick={fetchMore}>Moar comments</a>
    </div>


    var self = this;
    self.commentType = (self.opts.level === 0 ? "parent" : "child");
</comment-list>
```

and comment :

```
<comment>
    ... some html ...

    <div class="row" if={opts.level == 0}>
      <div class="col s11 offset-s1 m11 offset-m1 l11 offset-l1" style="padding-left: 0;">
        <comment-list level={1} fetchMore={fetchMore}></comment-list>
      </div>
    </div>
</comment>
```

**comment-list.tag** is initialized with level = 0. It is supposed to pass this level value to **comment.tag**. Problem is when I try to access *opts.level* in **comment.tag**, I get 'undefined'. Same goes for *ctype*. *type* is always "child" as if opts.level in **comment-list.tag** wasn't defined.

Ps: I don't think it might be due to 0 in comment-list being considered as null or 'undefined' as I have the same behavior with value 1 for instance
Do I do someting wrong passing a value straight from the opts object ?

Comment: I don´t know exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but some tips.
Mounts the tag correctly, in this case I added some initial values
`riot.mount('comment-list', {level:0, comments: [{level: 0}, {level: 1}] })` 
In your first each, are you trying to access the level from the opts parent, or from the children that you are iterating? Inside an each you are in the child context, so if you want the parent you have to do parent.opts.level . Here is a simplified example http://plnkr.co/edit/7znf8HJh1wnpX9bjrxIX?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The each creates a child scope so you need to look at the parent.

Change `{opts.level}` to `{parent.opts.level}`

So your `<comment-list>` is your current scope, and your `each={com in comments}` creates a child scope. Your `opts.level` belongs to the current/parent, not to the individual scope that's been iterated.

https://github.com/riot/riot/issues/1720

Here's the github issue i raised earlier this year for this exact question.